# How to switch to Python 3 from 2 on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, raspberry-pi

I'm operating on a Raspberry Pi through PuTTY, and I need it to use Python 3 instead of 2. I've already done alias python = python3, but that does not seem to change the default, only the keyword itself used. I want to change to 3 because for example, when I try to 'pip install selenium', I get the following prompt:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st,
> 2020. Please                                                                                                              upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0
> will drop s
> upport for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2
> support in pi
> p can be found at
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#pyt
> hon-2-support

And it won't even let me pip install selenium. After trying for a minute or two, it prompts me this:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium

My Linux machine has both Python 2 and 3 installed.

EDIT: Thank you for your contributions, I understand what you're saying. Now I have a new problem though - I broke sudo apt-get update by following someone else's suggestion. I have a post here: [Raspberry Pi sudo apt-get update doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827295/raspberry-pi-sudo-apt-get-update-doesnt-work)

Comment: Should not your alias be turned the other way round, "python=python3"? If you have both Python versions installed, try using `pip3` instead.

Comment: When doing pip3 install selenium, it prompts: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb5567950>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/selenium/

Comment: Also, I meant python=python3, wops.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410851 this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though you [can install python3 from apt](https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian/) on raspbian by doing the following steps:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install -y build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev tar wget vim
3. wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
4. Install the new version using the following commands, all typed in your PuTTY session:

a. sudo tar zxf Python-3.8.0.tgz

b. cd Python-3.8.0

c. sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations

d. sudo make -j 4

e. sudo make altinstall

5. Check that the installation can be found using `python3.8 -V`
6. Create a venv using `python3.8 -m venv selenium-venv`
7. Activate said venv using `. ./selenium-venv/bin/activate` in your shell.
8. Now it will work.

I hope that helps, leave a comment if you need further assistance.

Comment: Everything im doing with sudo apt-get prompts me Tempoary Failure resolving to 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org'?

Comment: Edit your question to include the contents of /etc/resolv.conf, please?

Comment: It was a whole other problem - I didn't have wifi on the Raspberry Pi apparently. Thank you for your help - the problem is not that I don't have Python3 however, but just that I wanted it to be default.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance, @Calle

Answer (score 0):

its probably because you assigned a variable "python3" to point to python (2.7) binary.
see if you made an env variable "python3":

**printenv python3**

if you did, unset it:

**unset python3**

to see where and what versions of python you have installed:

**locate /bin/python**

if you see "python" that is binary for 2.7, "python3" is the binary for 3.x

try to run it by typing the whole path in the terminal:
e.g. : **/usr/local/bin/python3**

if pip is not working try to upgrade or use pip3

Answer (score -1):

Python 3 should be the standard on all systems since the beginning of 2020. If you are not using some "old" software that depends on python 2 then you can remove python 2 from your OS.

`sudo apt remove python2`

Then there will be no confusion which python to use.

On raspbian or RaspberryOS i think they still use the versionnumber after the name. eg: `pyhton3`, `pip3` So when you run `pip` you have to run `pip3` check if you have it installed. You could also use `python3 -m pip`